# loading random objects, and drawing them onto screen

Tags: python, pygame

Im using python, pygame.

Im trying to display a random number of images to a window, heres how:

> Class sprite():
>
> ```
> def __init__(self):
>   self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
>   self.sprite=[[500,200]]
>
> def load_sprite(self, image, x,y):
>   image = pygame.image.load(image)
>   self.screen.blit(image,(x,y))
>   pygame.dsiplay.update()
>
> def load_sprites(self, image, x,y):
>    image = pygame.image.load(image)
>    self.screen.blit(image,(x,y))
>    pygame.display.update()
>
> def draw_random_sprites(self, rand1, rand2):
>    self.load_spites(0,200,random.randint(rand1,rand2))
> ```

When i call the flowing methods from the main class:

```
class Main():
   
    s = sprite()
    s.load_sprites(self, image, x,y): //here i want the user to determine the number of random sprites they load.
```

But, when i do this i get a

> cant seek data source error

Any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

**EDIT**

Heres the stack trace for the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\game\Main.py", line 15, in <module>
    s.draw_random_sprites(20,40)
  File "C:\Python33\game\sprite.py", line 29, in draw_random_sprites
    self.load_spites(0,200,random.randint(rand1,rand2))
  File "C:\Python33\game\sprite.py", line 22, in load_sprites
    image = pygame.image.load(image)
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
```

Comment: i have added it as an edit

Comment: mark line 22 in your code

Comment: it seems you are trying to load image `0`... `pygame.image.load()` expect a filename or a file handle

Comment: `load_spites`? Looks like a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spot two errors. The first one is here, where you essentially tell load_sprites to load image 0. You are placing that between 200 and a random integer.

```
self.load_spites(0,200,random.randint(rand1,rand2))
```

The tag image is passed as both an input and an output. This likely will cause some issues further down the line, unless that's exactly what you intended.

```
image = pygame.image.load(image)
```

Look at fixing these two items, and you should be able to make this work. A method of doing so might be:

```
self.load_spites("sprite.png",200,random.randint(rand1,rand2))

def load_sprites(self, image_file, x,y):
   image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
```

Comment: here it only displays one sprite, what if i wanted to generate the random number of sprites?

Comment: You could call the load_sprites function a random number of times, perhaps.

Comment: Isnt that what the draw_random_sprites function is suppose to do, draw a random number of sprites to the screen?

Comment: @Pro-grammer `draw_random_sprites()` calls `load_spites()` only once and `load_spites()` blit image only once so you get only one image on screen. Use loop.

Comment: How would i get more than one imgage, is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

To get random number of images (no less than 1, no more than 100)

```
def draw_random_sprites(self, rand1, rand2):
    for i in range(random.randint(1,100)):
        self.load_spites("sprite.png",200,random.randint(rand1,rand2))
```

by the way: `load_sprite()` and `load_sprites()` are identical so you can use `load_sprite()` in place of `load_sprites()` and delete `load_sprites()`

Comment: those were typos, i corrected. I wrote it out from my text editor. I dont know why i didnt copy and past tbh.

Comment: @Pro-grammer see how to get random number of images